# Can't print os.urandom()

Tags: python, python-2.7, printing

I have the following problem. I am trying to print the output of os.urandom(10) and I get nothing in the output. Now I have found a workaround by printing the repr of os.urandom but it is really weird especially considering that the actual type of os.urandom is string.

Does anyone have the same problem or knows why this happens?
I am using python 2.7 on Spyder and below is a copy of the phenomenon:

```
>>> import os
>>> out = os.urandom(10)
>>> print out
>>> out
'\x96\x02\x1b\xa9\xa2z\xc4\xf0\xa4\xfa'
>>> type(out)
<type 'str'>
>>> print repr(out)
'\x96\x02\x1b\xa9\xa2z\xc4\xf0\xa4\xfa'
```

Comment: help(os.urandom) clearly says it's got a random string for cryptographic use, so likely going to have some non-ascii hex characters. You can use binascii.hexlify as shown below.

Comment: @gabhijit os.urandom can return ASCII chars as well but it wouldn't print them as well.

Comment: well the ascii ones are printed. The non-ascii ones don't get printed, the ascii ones do get printed. hexlify - converts even those into hex. :-) but that's okay, you want something printable.(try `os.urandom(2)` a few times).

Answer (score 3):

Those are non-printing characters.  It's not reasonably possible to print them exactly as-is.  If you just want to take a hexdump, use [`binascii.hexlify()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/binascii.html#binascii.hexlify).

Comment: Can't you try to `print os.urandom(10).decode(some "ISO-XXXX").encode("UTF-8")` in order to print _something_?  Or cycle through decodings?

Comment: @wflynny: Most encodings don't put anything printable below `0x20`, because that's where ASCII control characters live.  There's no obvious way to turn those into printable characters.

Comment: @wflynny Yes I can use that command to print something. Thanks guys I thought it was weird.